# How to work with portaudio?

Tags: c, audio-processing

I am working in a project to record audio and process in real-time in C.For starting, I wanted to check how it works.
I downloaded the pa_stable_v190600_20161030.tgz from [here](http://www.portaudio.com/download.html).
I ran ,/configure and then ran make using WSL(Ubuntu) and then to test I ran ./pa_devs from the bin folder, but it returns 0 devices

I dont know what the problem is, for the moment I just want to get this working, is there any other method which I can try?

Comment: if you are using the native sound card, I'm not sure WSL exposes that to VMs. You could try using a USB sound card (you can use usbip to forward USB packets to/from VM using TCP/IP). Otherwise you could try experimenting with PulseAudio as described here: https://token2shell.com/howto/x410/enabling-sound-in-wsl-ubuntu-let-it-sing/

Comment: I already tried PulseAudio exactly as in the  link you provided, but I'm  running into the error they have mentioned there

Comment: Try getting a USB dongle sound card and setup usbip. I've used usbip (in WSL2 although I wouldn't think that makes a difference) to talk to microcontrollers and it works great. See here: https://github.com/rpasek/usbip-wsl2-instructions

Comment: thanks a lot  @David, I will try that!

Comment: [Ubuntu has a PortAudio package.  Install it and the PortAudio development package.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=portaudio)  That's  the "libportaudio2" package and the "portaudio19-dev."  You might also need the "libportaudiocpp0" package.

Comment: why would you want to do real-time audio in Windows Linux subsystem? WSL is far from perfect, and you're just adding more layers of abstraction. If you want to use Portaudio, simply do so natively under windows with portaudio (that's the whole point of portaudio, same API for Windows and Linux). Unless you write very platform-specific code around that, the same software would compile for linux, too.

Comment: I could not get the portaudio compiled in msys(MinGW),(some problem with the autotools), so I moved to WSL.Let me try that again, thanks for the suggestion!!